Java code skipping line without any reason
A Scanner object is being bypassed in the method and I don't know why. There is no errors or warmings. It simply skips it.
public class AccountView extends AccountController{
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    AccountController account = new AccountController();
    
    public void createNewAccount() {
        System.out.println("Enter account number: ");
        account.setAccountNumber(input.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Enter account holder: "); //<--- Prints this
        account.setHolderName(input.nextLine()); < --- But ignores that one
        
        System.out.println("There is a initial deposit? (y/n)");
        String initialDepositOption = input.nextLine();
        
        if(initialDepositOption.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the initial deposit value: ");
            account.setAmount(input.nextDouble());
        }
        
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

again: no IDE or runtime erros. What can be happening?
I tried to .close() at the Scanner object the call it again. It returns a error saying that the Scanner is closed. Then tried to add some "spacers" with println(). Nothing different happened.

This is because you do not clear the buffer after scanning for the int.
It scans the int, but  leaves the rest of the line blank and ready to be scanned, so when you call input.nextLine() it takes the remaining line from the int input, which happens to be nothing, but still enough to mess with your input.  You can add a line after you call input.nextInt() where it just says input.nextLine(); and this will clear the buffer and solve any issues
